# Updating/upsert/insert to a nested collection in Meteor & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have this collection and schema:

```
Words = new Mongo.Collection("words");

WordsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  date: {
    type: String
  },
  owner: {
    type: String
  },
  entries: {
    type: [Entry]
  }
});

Entry = new SimpleSchema({
  post: {
    type: String
  },
  elapsed_time: {
    type: Number
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date
  }
});

Words.attachSchema( WordsSchema );
```

I am simply trying to add entries to this collection, through UPSERT (or update with upsert = true), like this:

```
Words.update({
      date: today,
      owner: Meteor.userId()
    }, {
      $push: {
        entries: { post: post, elapsed_time: elapsed_time, createdAt: new Date() }
      }
    }, {
      upsert: true
    });
```

i.e. if an object with date = today (stored as 'YYYY-MM-DD') and owner = userId exists, it just adds the specific entry.

But I'm doing something wrong, as I get the error: "Entries is required".

Any help or ideas is very appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the problem with this. But I guess type: [Entry] is not support by the simple schema. So here you can try these two methods to achieve same functionality.
1. Marge both schema.

```
WordsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  date: {
    type: String
  },
  owner: {
    type: String
  },
  entries: {
    type: Array
  }
  "entries.$": {
    type: Object
  },
  "entries.$.post: {
    type: String
  },
  "entries.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
  },
"entries.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
  }
});
```

2. By using $ you can seperate both schemas

```
WordsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  date: {
    type: String
  },
  owner: {
    type: String
  },
  entries: {
    type: Array
  }
  "entries.$": {
    type: Entry
  }
});

Entry = new SimpleSchema({
  post: {
    type: String
  },
  elapsed_time: {
    type: Number
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date
  }
});
```